# How to scroll from waypoint to waypoint in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

In my webpage I have 4 "waypoints" that have their respective links in a menu. What I need is to also bind the scroll of the page to these waypoints. So when the page loads, the pointer is at the top and based on the scrolling direction, the page moves to the next/previous waypoint. Until now I have come up with this simplistic approach, which goes into a scroll loop due to the `scrollTo()` function triggering the whole method again.

```
$(function () {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var currentWaypoint = 0;
    var previousWaypoint = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log("Scroll triggered");
        console.log("Current Waypoint: " + currentWaypoint);
        var curTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (top < curTop) {
            if (currentWaypoint < 4) {
                previousWaypoint = currentWaypoint;
                currentWaypoint=currentWaypoint+1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (currentWaypoint > 0) {
                previousWaypoint = currentWaypoint;
                currentWaypoint=currentWaypoint-1;
            }
        }
        top = curTop;
        if (previousWaypoint != currentWaypoint) {
            switch (currentWaypoint) {
            case 1:
                $.scrollTo(document.getElementById("waypoint-collection"));
            case 2:
                $.scrollTo(document.getElementById("waypoint-report"));
            case 3:
                $.scrollTo(document.getElementById("waypoint-video"));
            case 4:
                $.scrollTo(document.getElementById("waypoint-mail"));
            default:
            }
        }
        console.log("New Waypoint: " + currentWaypoint);
    });
});
```

I've seen this sort of behaviour implemented in some websites but cannot seem to find anything relevant with google. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The relevant HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .features-container-wh {
            min-height: 12.5rem;
            text-align: center;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .features-container-bl {
            background-color: #43bfcb;
            text-align: center;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .features-container-bottom {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="features-container-wh">
        <a href="#waypoint-collection">Collection</a>
        <a href="#waypoint-report">Report</a>
        <a href="#waypoint-video">Video</a>
        <a href="#waypoint-mail">Mail</a>
    </div>
    <div class="features-container-bl" id="waypoint-collection">
        <p>Stuff...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-container-wh" id="waypoint-report">
        <p>Stuff...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-container-bl" id="waypoint-video">
        <p>Stuff...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="features-container-bottom" id="waypoint-mail">
        <p>Stuff...</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add more details?  what's HTML look like? how it currently behaves ? and if possible a link to the desired behavior.

Comment: At the moment the scrolling behaves as default (I suppose this is browser dependent) but it's a normal scroll. I do not have any examples as I cannot remember the websites I came across that feature this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#.wayPoint1").offset().top}, 2000);
```